# How to create workflow graphs in js

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg, raphael, jsplumb

I want to create work flow charts with good styling and drag and drop feature which creates new shapes(scalable shapes such as circle, round rectangles, arrows/connectors etc) as in this link: http://rigrr.rapilabs.com/

I want to achieve exact functionality as in the link. If you see in the page source, the site have used png images, innersvg.js, cssparser.js, canvg etc.

I have been looking at d3.js, jsplumb, sigms.js and couldn't exact documentation or solution for it to say which javascript library is suitable for my requirement.

I have created a draggable and stretchable circle using d3 in this [link](http://jsbin.com/sukowabili/edit?html,js,output). Similarly I want to create a arrow connectors and shapes which are created on drag and drop.

Which js library is suitable for this along with good css styling(important) and future customizations

Comment: I can't speak for any of the other libraries you mentioned, but you would also certainly be able to create a similar program using d3. That said, it would probably be a fairly lengthy process. You could have a `g` element at the side with all the shapes (classed with .drag and mouseover cursor). When the drag event registers `x>[threshold]`, then append one of those to the main svg area. Use path elements to represent lines, etc. D3 is also pretty great for CSS because you can easily use `.style(<name>, <setting>)` to change properties of many items at once.

Comment: How about jsjoint? Heard its suitable for work flows but would I be able to achieve it with good styling and decision making flow with jsjoint or d3?

Comment: Also I didn't see option of using connector points on shapes for like arrows to connect in d3

Comment: Personally, I would probably see if its possible to integrate Snap.svg (which has graffle for links eg http://svg.dabbles.info/snaptut-graffle and jsplumb and see how well they play.

Comment: jsPlumb doesn't support  css style customization

Comment: @lan How can I create links out of one svg container to other by drag and drop as in the example link I have provided in question

Comment: Do some bounding collision or intersection testing, depending on accuracy vs performance.

Comment: @lan any links or example??

Comment: http://www.inkfood.com/collision-detection-with-svg/

Comment: @lan Thanks for the link. I am not sure how collision detection is related to my requirement. May be I am still new to svg and d3js

Comment: How else are you going to check if one element is over another without some test ?

Comment: @lan I meant drag and create and svg element out of box(svg container). Check the link I have provided, you will get an idea. To create new shapes, I am just dragging and dropping them

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/82271/discussion-between-ian-and-kittu).

Comment: Bit late to the party, but [here](http://bl.ocks.org/rkirsling/5001347) is an example of connecting lines between objects in D3.

Comment: (Closed question, but a top link on Google) In 2023, the [Mermaid.js](https://mermaid.js.org/) library does this reasonably well.

Comment: Even after 7 years, I am getting notifications with popular question badge so I thought I will answer what I tried.. I have achieved it using jointjs library: https://www.jointjs.com/